# Architecture with smaller vs bigger machines for heavy load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-testing, scaling, amazon-ecs

We have a small application with AngularJS frontend and NodeJS backend. We need to host it for more number of users, say 100,000. We have containerized the app and going to use AWS ECS for hosting the application.

I have created separate clusters for frontend and backend in AWS ECS. But I'm not sure what EC2 instance (machine) type should I choose?

I'm planning to create 48 containers to handle the load. Each container has a hard limit of 500MB, so it won't use beyond that value. Which instance (machine) should I use?

1. A cluster of bigger machines. Eg: 3 X 8GB RAM contains 48 containers (16 containers on each machine).
2. A cluster of smaller machines. Eg: 12 X 2GB RAM contains 48 containers (4 containers on each machine).

What I thought was:

- For smaller machine, for example, a t2.small (2GB RAM, 2vCPU) which contain 4 containers share the 2GB memory and 2vCPU among those 4 containers.
- But for larger machines, for example, an 8GB RAM machine with 2vCPU contain 16 containers share the 8GB memory and **ALSO SHARE THIS SAME 2vCPU**

So I used the smaller machine approach. But is there any other factor that I miss??

Comment: Small enough that you end up with enough nodes in the cluster to weather at least one node failing at a time.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might also want to look at network bandwidth. T2 instances, for example, have low network performance. Also, you should consider how your load will vary over time. If you have a load that is fairly constant, A T2 instance might not be the best choice because you may consume all of your CPU credits.